# How to get data from esp32 Micropython html webserver?

Tags: javascript, html, esp32, micropython

Im new to Micropython and currently workring on a IoT Project with the esp32S3 using Micropython. For the iniziallisation I would like the user to be able to select a WLAN and enter the corresponding password. I was able to scan WLANs, connect to the esp32S3 as an accesspoint and send html code in order to set up a side. However now Im kind of clueless on how to get the userinput back to the esp32.

So far I have written the following code:

```
import network
import gc
import socket


def format_scan(scan_results):
    ssids = [result[0].decode("utf-8") for result in scan_results]
    ssids = list(set(ssids))
    if '' in ssids:
        ssids.remove('')
    form_results = []
    for ssid in ssids:
        rssis = []
        for result in scan_results:
            if result[0].decode("utf-8") == ssid:
                rssis.append(result[3])
        form_results.append((ssid, max(rssis)))
    return form_results


def format_html(wlans):
    html_wlan_tab = """<table>"""
    for index, wlan in enumerate(wlans):
        html_wlan_tab += """
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="wlan" id=""" + f"\"{index}\"" + """>
            </td>
            <td>
                """ + f"{wlan[0]}" + """
            </td>
            <td>
                """ + f"{wlan[1]}" + """
            </td>
        </tr>"""
    html_wlan_tab += """
    </table>"""
    html_code = """
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>WLAN Selector</title>
        </head>
        <style>
            
        </style>
        <body>
            <h2>Wählen Sie ein WLAN</h2>
            """ + html_wlan_tab + """
            <div>
                <h2>Passwort eingeben</h2>
                <input type="password">
                <button>bestätigen </button>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
    """
    return html_code


gc.collect()

# WLAN Konfiguration
wlan_ap = network.WLAN(network.AP_IF)       # AP Objekt
wlan_sta = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)     # Station Objekt
wlan_sta.active(True)
wlan_werte = format_scan(wlan_sta.scan())
html = format_html(wlan_werte)
print(html)
wlan_sta.active(False)
wlan_ap.active(True)
wlan_ap.config(essid="SmartSwitch")

# Socket Konfiguration
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind(('', 80))
server_socket.listen(1)

try:
    while True:
        com_socket, com_adr = server_socket.accept()
        com_socket.sendall(html)
        com_socket.close()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Programm durch REPL unterbrochen")
```

It scans for available WLANs (in Station mode) and sets up a web server (http://192.168.4.1) in access point mode using HTML.
[it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giizY.png)

I would appreciate some help on how to write the script (JavaScript) which would be necessary to...
...get the user input (ID of the selected WiFi and password) back to the ESP32 so that I can receive it using socket.receive() or something similar.
...make sure a radio button (WLAN) is selected when the button "bestätigen" is pressed.
Thanks in advance for your help and thoughts on my project.